# Celery tasks registering in multiple queues

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am using celery in Django (1.9) with RabbitMQ server. I have four different queues and I am registering a task in one of these four queues.

The issue is all my tasks are registered in all four queue. Like I have a task named **add** and have four queues A, B, C and D. Ideally task should be registered in only A queue (As I registered) But It is showing in all four queues.

could not rectify what is the actual issue. Please help.

Comment: How did you define your queues? it could be that they are all receiving the message from the same exchange. Check here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#exchanges-queues-and-routing-keys